# mysql - Consultar 3 tabelas ao mesmo tempo

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tenho 3 tabelas, e precisa fazer um SELECT dentro de um LOOP nas 3 ao mesmo tempo, ficaria da seguinte forma: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

notem que o resultado, eu pego o username onde ficaria na coluna NOME, FAÇO um num_rows pra exibir a quantidade de vendas e adiciono em VENDAS e a soma dos produtos vendidos por cada usuario.

Eu encontrei algumas coisas semelhantes no site, mas não consegui adaptar...
Tentei algo como, porem não consigo adapta-lo ao meu caso.

```sql
SELECT a.ticket_lote_id, 
       COALESCE(SUM(b.lote_preco), 0) AS lote_preco
  FROM vendidos a LEFT JOIN ingress b ON b.lote_id = a.ticket_id
 GROUP BY a.venda_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tenta assim :

```
SELECT 
   u.username, count(v.lote_id) as quantidade_vendas, SUM(p.lote_preco) as total
from USERS u
join VENDAS v on v.user_id = u.username
join PRODUTOS p on p.lote_id = v.lote_id
order by total DESC
Group by u.username;
```

Comment: Testei dessa forma, porem ele me retornou um valor total de todos... não de usuario por usuario... Tentei colocar dentro do loop (WHILE) porem ele ainda sim me retorna somente 1 resultado e o valor total errado tambem. (esta somando de todos os usuarios, não de cada usuario em uma lista).

Comment: editei a query agora agrupa por username